# Liferay - How to i18n model-resources?

Tags: internationalization, liferay, liferay-6, roles, role

How can I translate my custom model-resources?
Given the following `default.xml`:

```xml
<model-resource>
    <model-name>de.foo.db.model.FooBar</model-name>
    <portlet-ref>
        <portlet-name>myportlet</portlet-name>
    </portlet-ref>
    <permissions>
        <supports>
            <action-key>DECLINE_OWNER</action-key>
            <action-key>DECLINE_DEPARTMENT</action-key>
        </supports>
        <site-member-defaults/>
        <guest-defaults/>
        <guest-unsupported>
            <action-key>DECLINE_OWNER</action-key>
            <action-key>DECLINE_DEPARTMENT</action-key>
        </guest-unsupported>
        <owner-defaults/>
    </permissions>
</model-resource>
```

When I want to define these permissions for a role `Control-panel-> roles-> myRole-> define permissions`
they get listed as:

- model.resource.de.foo.db.model.FooBar:action.DECLINE_OWNER
- model.resource.de.foo.db.model.FooBar:action.DECLINE_DEPARTMENT

But I'd like them to show up as:

- FooBar: Decline own element
- FooBar: Decline element for own department

I'm running Liferay 6.2 EE.

Comment: Identical problem was later successfully answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28118987/401095

Answer (score 0):

You can add below language properties for all actions in Language properties file.

```
action.DECLINE_OWNER=FooBar: Decline own element
action.DECLINE_DEPARTMENT= FooBar: Decline element for own department
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I added those entries to `src/main/resources/Language_en_US.properties`, but they show up as before.

Comment: Would you check that Language_en_US is configured properly in portlet.xml