# Liferay custom portlet permission label missing

Tags: permissions, liferay, liferay-6, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I've followed the instructions from [this tutorial](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Permissioning+in+Plugin+Environment) to introduce a new portlet level permission for my custom portlet.

In the resource-action-mapping XML there is a new action-key called `PARTNER_ADMIN_CONTRACTING`, and I've added the following line to the `Language.properties` file:

```
action.PARTNER_ADMIN_CONTRACTING=Admin contracting
```

On the `Define permissions` tab, it still shows the label key, not the value:

[image: custom portlet permission label is missing]

What's missing?

Comment: Have you specified `<resource-bundle>content.Language</resource-bundle>` in portlet.xml of your portlet.? It seems you haven't specified this entry and hence key itself is appearing instead of value.

Comment: yes, it's in my portlet.xml as follows: `<resource-bundle>Language</resource-bundle>`. actually, other labels in my custom portlet working perfectly

Comment: Is Language.properties file resides directly under src folder? can you provide what key-value you have written

Comment: it's under src/main/resources
the key-value is in the question

Comment: Then you have to provide it as `<resource-bundle>resources.Language</resource-bundle>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the `action.PARTNER_ADMIN_CONTRACTING=Admin contracting` language key to the portal resource bundle, because the Control Panel does not look for the translation in your portlet. You can use the [language hook](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/overriding-language-properties-using-a-hook) feature do to this:

1. Create a `liferay-hook.xml` in your `docroot/WEB-INF` directory:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_6_2_0.dtd">

   <hook>
      <language-properties>content-portal/Language.properties</language-properties>
   </hook>
   ```
2. Create `docroot/WEB-INF/src/content-portal/Language.properties`:

   ```
   action.PARTNER_ADMIN_CONTRACTING=Admin contracting
   ```

This should work!